# Informatica Time error ,not matching souce and target data

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

One of my source table(oracle) date column having the value 5/3/2013 6:00:51.134000000 AM. I am trying to pull the same into to my target(oracle), but my target converted the micro seconds as "zeros" and loading the value 5/3/2013 06.00.51.000000000 AM. Both my source & target column has declared as timestamp. I have set the date format like MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US in session properties

Can anyone help to me to get the date with micro seconds? I am using informatica 10.2.0 Thx

Comment: Can you share the datatypes used in mapping, target and target DB?

Comment: Target(DB) :TIMESTAMP(9)  mapping level target :TIMESTAMP(29P)(9 S) and in all Transformations  DATE/TIME(29)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the workaround suggested at the below link to process high precision dates. You will need to modify the source and target definition field lengths to (29,9).

[Link](https://archive.is/joxoE)

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve this is to increase the precision of the source or target definition to precision 29 and scale 9 after the source/target is imported into Informatica. This will handle the digits in milliseconds without converting them to all zeros.